# Capturing two information using regular expressions

Tags: regex

```
*COMPLETED:     25 Apr 2020 [09:08:21]                            |TIME:        00:13:49  *
```

I would like to capture the information as below:
DateEnd : 25 Apr 2020 [09:08:21]
Duration: 00:13:49

I have tried the regular expression below but unable to correctly get the right information.

```
(?P<DateEnd>(?<=\*COMPLETED\:).+)]\s+(?P<Duration>(?<=\|TIME\:).+)\*
```

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: `(?<=\*COMPLETED\:)\s+(?<DateEnd>.+])\s+\|TIME\:\s*(?<Duration>\S+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
COMPLETED: *(?<DateEnd>.+?]).*TIME: *(?<Duration>\S+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/UbYpog99hLHL9Z).

You don't need to escape colons `:` and you don't need look arounds.

I'm not sure if your flavour of regex needs the `P` in the named groups, but none I know need the `P` so I removed them and as per the demo it works.